# Eink powerline cutoff

Tags: transistors, e-ink

I'm experimenting with an eink panel (ED060SC4), powered by a TPS65185EVM.
It's all working well exept when i'm done updating the panel image and I have shutdown the power chip, there is still some lingerring voltage (between 20 and 160 mV) on randomely some of the 4 main power lines (+22V, -20V, +15V, -15V). 
The problem is this small voltages cause the panel image to slowly fade toward grey (quickly in the first few seconds then more slowly).
I blame it on the capacitors that are on those power lines but as I'm stuck using this power board for various reason, I'm looking into a way to cut off the power lines when i'm not using them.

I was thinking of using transistors as switch to cut those power lines junction when not in use but i'm afraid it will reduce the voltage arriving to the pannel, possibly impeding it's working and also that some small voltage may still pass through it when "closed".

I also thought of using relays but the noise they emit will be a nuisance in this project.

Have you any recommandation in the matter ?

Comment: Why are you afraid? What is the RDS(on) of your transistor? How large is its leakage current?

Comment: I'm afraid because I havn't used transistors before and I'm fairly new to the whole world of electronic engineering. on the MOSFETs I was looking into, the RDS(on) were between 400 and 200 mOhm, depending on the component. The leakage i want to prevent is beween 20 and 160 mv, sometimes in inverse polarity of the line (like a +120mV on a normally -20V power line)

Comment: 120 mA × 400 mΩ = 48 mV